# How does :w !tee work in Vim

Tags: vim

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12001737/1833960) answer states that `:w !tee` writes current buffer to stdout. Why and how does it work? Can I write `:x !tee` or `:w !cat`? What's exclamation mark meaning in this case? (I assume it's not forcing operation.) Does it work only if `tee` command exists (not on Windows)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!` tells `vim` that it's a shell command and not a filename. So `:w !tee` or `:w !cat` gives the vim buffer to those commands as input. They in turn send the buffer content to `stdout`.

Try `:w !wc -l`, this will give you number of lines in your buffer printed on `stdout`.

You can also read output from a command into vim buffer. You can use `read` command with a shell command. For example, `:read !date` executes the `date` command on shell and sends the output back to vim buffer.

Comment: Thanks, it's getting clearer for me! Using your answer, I managed to find [documentation page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Display_output_of_shell_commands_in_new_window).